# Why Spring Boot 4 "custom error page" fails 404?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I tried to implement an own error page handling.But my page doesnt show up.
Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyCustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/error", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String handleError() {

    return "error";
}

@Override
public String getErrorPath() {

    return "/error";
}}
```

I did my own error.html file in src/main/resources/static/html.
The html folder is created by myself. Where is the problem?

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Do you have thymeleaf dependency ?

Comment: no i don't use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open your html file from static content like

```
localhost:8080/yourpagename
```

By default, Spring boot serves `index.html` as the root resource when accessing the root URL of a web application.

`(yourhtml).html` should exist under any of these paths:

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/home.html

src/main/resources/resources/home.html

src/main/resources/static/home.html

src/main/resources/public/home.html
```

In order to view your `error.html` static page you need to return `“error.html”` in controller

In order to define your own static resource locations 
you could use this property in `application.properties` or `application.yml` file :

```
spring.resources.static-locations=your own locations
```

Comment: I swapped the error.html file out of my under folder from static to static. my structure was: statitc/html/error.html. Can't i do  subfolders for static?

Comment: You can do subfolders

Comment: thank you very much i got now my error which i searched. first i must give the subfolder also back with my html file in the controller: /html/error.html